# CSS/HTML - Div inside div not being placed correctly

Tags: html, css, django

This is an attached image which provides some background for my problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQXh8.jpg

I am having trouble styling a div inside a div. What happens is that when I double-click the text in that div, you can see that the highlighting is only highlighting half the div.

The second thing that I want to do is make sure there is no spacing between the wysiwyg editor and the header div.

I am using Django-ckeditor for the text editor. That is rendered by the {{form}} template tag. (I am obviously using the django web framework for this app).

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="hero clearfix">
<div class="title">
    <h2>{{subsection_title}}</h2>
</div>
<br>
<div class="subsection">
    <div class="subsection_header ">
        <h4 style="text-align:left">Something interesting.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="subsection_body">
    <p>lol</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
 .subsection {
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
}
.subsection_header {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:0px;
}
.subsection_body {
    margin:0px;
}

.hero {
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
```

Comment: you are missing `</div>` at the end.

Comment: whoops, that was a mistake with copying/pasting code into here; div was there in the actual code editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try some thing like this According to how your page width is and for yes remember to close the end tag

.

```
hero clearfix
{
   position:absolute;
   width:980px;
   margin-left:-490px;
   left:50%;
}
```

it may help you.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't really help. I also feel like that solution is non-ideal because anytime a browser gets resized, every element will look weird.

Comment: Ok you need to center your main Div tag so that the rest stay the same check on this link:http://www.w3schools.com or google how to center a html page in css it will help you